# Fullscreen mode seems to cause different softInputMode behavior

Tags: android, android-activity, fullscreen

It seems that when the Activity is in fullscreen mode, it seems that the softInputMode does not adjust the underlying views for the desired scroll up behavior. Within onCreate(...):

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

The view structure consists of a scroll view and a linear layout within a relative layout. The idea is that the linear layout makes a "button bar" that should be tied to the bottom of the window, but move up to stay above the keyboard. When full screen mode is not set, this works OK, but not when the first line above is added.

Any ideas?

Thanks!